# Making scientific notation readable from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-notation

How do I convert an array like:

`array([ -9.8737e+13,  -9.8737e+13,  -1.1265e+14,   1.5743e-01,
         1.1265e+14,   9.8737e+13,   9.8737e+13])`

into a readable form in `numpy` or `python`?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Looks readable to me as it is. :^)  What format are you looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Your array contains both large and small values. It's hard to present both in a readable way. If you use scientific notation the numbers can be shown in a compact form, but it's hard to tell at a glance which numbers are large and which are small.

Alternatively, you could display the floats without scientific notation, for example, like this:

```
In [132]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':'{:25f}'.format})

In [133]: x
Out[133]: 
array([   -98737000000000.000000,    -98737000000000.000000,
         -112650000000000.000000,                  0.157430,
          112650000000000.000000,     98737000000000.000000,
           98737000000000.000000])
```

which makes it easy to distinguish the large from the small, but now the eyes boggle looking at too many zeros.

After a while, you may want to go back to NumPy's default format, which you can do by calling `np.set_printoptions()` without arguments.

```
In [134]: np.set_printoptions()

In [135]: x
Out[135]: 
array([ -9.8737e+13,  -9.8737e+13,  -1.1265e+14,   1.5743e-01,
         1.1265e+14,   9.8737e+13,   9.8737e+13])
```

Whatever the case, the above shows you how you can configure NumPy to display floats (or other types) any way you wish. See [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) for more on all the available options.

Comment: Is there a way to enable scientific notation only for small numbers? e.g. it would look like [9.8e-10, 0.54]

Comment: @Leo: `np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float':'{:g}'.format})` would work in that case. See the precision type table in the [string formatting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for info on what the `g` "general format" does.