# Converting dataframe to numpy array causes all numbers to be printed in scientific notation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

To do the cross validation with scikit learn, I try to convert the dataframe to numpy array in advance. so I tried the function df.as_matrix() , it turns out the data looks weird. I wonder if it's normal. Why it has to be display in this strange format?

for example : 585 becomes 5.85000000e+02  ,and
               0  becomes  0.00000000e+00

Comment: It doesn't have to be displayed in that strange format. For example, when I create a 2x2 float matrix with the values 585, 0, 0, 585 and `print` it, I see them as `585.` and `0.`. Show us your code and maybe we can tell you why it _is_ being displayed in that format.

Comment: I am guessing you came across floating point precision/rounding errors, which is not really related to numpy.

Comment: You should really, *really* understand [scientific notation](http://www.chem.tamu.edu/class/fyp/mathrev/mr-scnot.html) if you do any kind of number crunching.

Comment: There was a clear question here that was not debugging (why do numpy arrays often print in scientific notation?), and an answer that explained why hours before this was closed. What was the point of closing it, beyond an attempt at being insulting to the person asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you have large/small values in your array that need scientific notation to be reasonable: in that case, numpy prints all the values in scientific notation. For example:

```
In [65]: z
Out[65]:
array([[  1.00000000e+10,   1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00],
       [  2.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])

In [66]: z[0,0]
Out[66]: 10000000000.0

In [67]: z[0,0]=1

In [68]: z
Out[68]:
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1.]])
```

The behavior can be modified with [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html), but you'd need to figure out what behavior you want. `suppress=` does not actually work if you have large numbers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21897953/599265) for a bit more.

Essentially, numpy wants your numbers printed *consistently*, rather than having each printed in the most convenient format. It does not appear that there's an easy way to change this, short of writing your own float formatter and passing it to `set_printoptions`.

---

Actually, try this:

```
In [102]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float':"{:6.5g}".format})

In [103]: z
Out[103]:
array([[  1e+10,       1,       2],
       [      2,       1,       1]])
```

This essentially tells numpy to format floats as they'd be formatted by python's `format` with `"{:6.5g}"` as the [format specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).